# How do I create a module that also has access to local variables?

Tags: ruby, module, scope

I am trying to create a set of methods accessible by just running `Name.method` where name is the same for all of the methods. I also need the methods to be able to access the variables from where they were called.

Here is what I currently have:

```
module Name
    def self.method1
        p "method1 called"
    end
    def self.accessLocalVariables
        p localVariable
    end
end
Name.method1 #=> method1 called
localVariable = "test"
Name.accessLocalVariables #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `localvariable' for Name:Module
```

I would like for `Name.accessLocalVariables` to have returned `test`. How could I create something that would work that way?

The reason why it must access local variables and I cannot instead use a different type of variable is because the variable is a part of a gem and I would have to go into the gem and find every instance and change it. It would not be feasible to do.

Comment: Why you wanna do that? That's very anti-encapsulation, tight coupling and bug-prone.

Comment: @Aetherus I am trying to group those methods together, which is why I'm using a module. Should I not be using a module?

Comment: In short, a method can't access a local variable defined elsewhere. That's not only in Ruby, but in all serious programming languages.

Comment: @Aetherus So does it not make sense to to try to do what I'm doing? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You are right. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Aetherus If you would write that up as an answer I would accept that, because that is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method can't access any local variables defined elsewhere, so it is not possible doing this. You have to pass the values of local variables to the method's parameters.

Comment: That's why they are called "local" variables, after all. If they were accessible from somewhere else, they wouldn't be "local".